# Objects are not valid as a React child using react router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

This is my wrapper component aka auth component to allow only authed user to access.

**Auth.js**

```
render() {
    const { Component: component, ...rest } = this.props;

    return (
      <Route>
        {rest}
        render={props =>
          this.isAuth === true ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/login"
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      </Route>
    );
  }
```

What's wrong with it? Here's my route declaration

**Index.js**

```
render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Auth path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I've made a demo to reproduce the problem here
https://codesandbox.io/s/5xm202p1j4

I used the same concept in the official doc, https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow just that instead of making the auth.js a pure function I make it a class base container so that I can call api or check the token of the user exist or not in my localstorage, what's the problem exactly?

Comment: I think trying to render `rest` is your problem maybe

Comment: @Tony rest is a variable from prop, I didn't pass into the render, it belongs to the `<Route>`

Comment: it's outside of `<Route>`, did you mean to do `<Route {...rest}>`?

Comment: `render` also needs to be inside the opening `<Route>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to do something like this:

```
render() {
  const { Component: component, ...rest } = this.props;

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        this.isAuth === true ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login"
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

By having `rest` and `render` in the `<Route>` tag so the `rest` are passed to the `<Route>`?

Comment: My bad, my careless mistake, thanks for the spot Tony!

Comment: but if this.isAuth is false it won't redirect, why?

Comment: that's a different question @JamieAden

Comment: there's no point it can't do redirect with this structure if it can't redirect.